# Efficient data structure for storing a long sequence of (mostly consecutive) integers

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

I'd like a data structure to efficiently store a long sequence of numbers. The numbers should always be whole integers, let's say Longs.

The feature of the inputs I'd like to leverage (to claim 'efficiency') is that the longs will be *mostly* consecutive. There can be missing values. And the values can be interacted with out of order.

I'd like the data structure to support the following operations:

- addVal(n): add a single value, n
- addRange(n, m): add all values between n and m, inclusive
- delVal(n): remove a single value, n
- delRange(n, m): remove all values between n and m, inclusive
- containsVal(n): return whether a single value, n, exists in the structure
- containsRange(n, m): return whether all values between n and m, incluse, exist in the structure

In essence this is a more specific kind of Set data structure that can leverage the continuity of the data to use less than O(n) memory, where n is the number of values stored.

To be clear, while I think an efficient implementation of such a data structure will require that we store intervals internally, that isn't visible or relevant to the user. There are some interval trees that store multiple intervals separately and allow operations to find the number of intervals that overlap with a given point or interval. But from the user perspective this should behave exactly like a set (except for the range-based operations so bulk additions and deletions can be handled efficiently).

**Example:**

```
dataStructure = ...
dataStructure.addRange(1,100) // [(1, 100)]
dataStructure.addRange(200,300) // [(1, 100), (200, 300)]
dataStructure.addVal(199) // [(1, 100), (199, 300)]
dataStructure.delRange(50,250) // [(1, 49), (251, 300)]
```

My assumption is this would best be implemented by some tree-based structure but I don't have a great impression about how to do that yet.
I wanted to learn if there was some commonly used data structure that already satisfies this use case, as I'd rather not reinvent the wheel. If not, I'd like to hear how you think this could best be implemented.

Comment: @Terminus huh, I didn't know of that exchange. I'm not familiar with the distinction. Is there a reason you think this question is more appropriate there?

Comment: What if you store pairs (left endpoint, right endpoint) in a BST, ordering by left endpoint only. Treat single integers `n` as `(n,n)`. An insertion that creates an interval of length >=1 by convention adjusts the right endpoint of one of the nodes. Then it looks like all of your operations are `O(log n)`, with space complexity 'O(n)` worst case.

Comment: I think your question is practical enough for SO; algorithm questions are ok here, that's what the [algorithm] tag is for. (Some users disagree, though.)

Comment: Sounds like you want an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). Since you'll be updating it frequently, you probably want the Augmented tree construction rather than the Centered tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't care about duplicates, then your intervals are non-overlapping. You need to create a structure that maintains that invariant. If you need a query like numIntervalsContaining(n) then that is a different problem.

You could use a BST that stores pairs of endpoints, as in a C++ `std::set<std::pair<long,long>>`. The interpretation is that each entry corresponds to the interval `[n,m]`. You need a weak ordering - it is the usual integer ordering on the left endpoint. A single `int` or `long` `n` is inserted as `[n,n]`. We have to maintain the property that all node intervals are non-overlapping. A brief evaluation of the order of your operations is as follows. Since you've already designated `n` I use `N` for the size of the tree.

- addVal(n): add a single value, n : `O(log N)`, same as a `std::set<int>`. Since the intervals are non-overlapping, you need to find the predecessor of `n`, which can be done in `O(log n)` time (break it down by cases as in https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-find-successors-and-predecessors-in-a-binary-search-tree-in-order). Look at the right endpoint of this predecessor, and extend the interval or add an additional node `[n,n]` if necessary, which by left-endpoint ordering will always be a right child. Note that if the interval is extended (inserting `[n+1,n+1]` into a tree with node `[a,n]` forming the node `[a,n+1]`) it may now bump into the next left endpoint, requiring another merge. So there are a few edge cases to consider. A little more complicated than a simple BST, but still `O(log N)`.
- addRange(n, m): `O(log N)`, process is similar. If the interval inserted intersects nontrivially with another, merge the intervals so that the non-overlapping property is maintained. The worst case performance is `O(n)` as pointed out below as there is no upper limit on the number of subintervals consumed by the one we are inserting.
- delVal(n): `O(log N)`, again `O(n)` worst case as we don't know how many intervals are contained in the interval we are deleting.
- delRange(n, m): remove all values between n and m, inclusive : `O(log N)`
- containsVal(n): return whether a single value, n, exists in the structure : `O(log N)`
- containsRange(n, m): return whether all values between n and m, inclusive, exist in the structure : `O(log N)`

Note that we can maintain the non-overlapping property with correct add() and addRange() methods, it is already maintained by the delete methods. We need `O(n)` storage at the worst.

Note that all operations are `O(log N)`, and inserting the range `[n,m]` is nothing like `O(m-n)` or `O(log(m-n))` or anything like that.

I assume you don't care about duplicates, just membership. Otherwise you may need an interval tree or KD-tree or something, but those are more relevant for float data...

Comment: I don't see how your addRange(n, m) and delRange(n, m) can be O(log N) in general, since they may intersect with arbitrarily many existing ranges.  (E.g.: The data structure initially contains every even number between 1 and 1 million, and then you call addRange(1, 1000000).)

Comment: Yeah, I think it is `O(log n)` average, `O(n)` worst case, just like an unbalanced BST, but for a different reason. Improving that might require a different structure.

Comment: Inserting may be a problem as it does require an evaluation of right endpoints. A separate tree with right endpoints doesn't work as the merge problem is `O(n)`. Hmm....

Comment: In terms of complexity analysis, in the worst case the type of continuity I'm hoping to leverage could just not exist and therefore the runtime could be approximately poop.
But I want something with operations that run as a function of the number of contiguous intervals which for my use case is likely to be << n. Also while I was hoping (and still hope) that modifying whole ranges of numbers would be faster than modifying the set for each number in sequence, that's not a requirement exactly.
-- Still looking over your solution, will accept/comment further once I do so :).

Comment: I think if you can eliminate lots of small non-overlapping intervals from your typical use-case, the above might work. Otherwise, no, it approaches linked-list worst case.

Comment: The worst-case performance, is, as you state, "approximately poop", i.e. &Theta;(N), where N is the number of non-adjacent intervals, it is *amortized* &Theta;(log N). Assign a tree of size N a potential of cN for some constant c. `addRange` and `deleteRange` take &Theta;(log N) time to look up the predecessor, then kc time to remove all the intervals contianed in their argument, where k is the number of intervals removed and c is a constant. The kc term is amortized free by release the same amount of potential. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_method

Comment: @jbapple removing intervals contained in a larger range can take `O(log n)` time independent of `k`, the number of the contained intervals, if the tree orders the intervals, which is exactly what a rope does (see my answer). In that case, a whole section of the tree is unlinked, rather than going interval by interval.

Comment: @גלעדברקן, Does your comment serve a purpose other than to point to your answer below and claim it is better?

Comment: @jbapple how ironic is your comment - at this time, the only (+1) vote on this, Charles' answer, is my own, lol.

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian could you help me understand why you couldn't have a balanced version of your tree, where you could keep an `O(log n)` complexity?

Comment: @j_random_hacker why would you have to visit all 500,000 nodes when adding [1,1000000] to a tree of even numbers between 1 and 1000000? wouldn't you just run down the tree to the lowest and then the highest, in O(log n), unlinking only the nodes on the way, which would hold subtrees containing nodes that wouldn't need to be visited (although, granted, would need to be handled as garbage after the relevant `O(log n)` nodes have been updated)?

Comment: This is basically the scheme I had already designed (and begun implementing) but the problem I ran into was exactly in the insertion (or deletion) of large ranges that could overlap with many other existing intervals which would then require that those nodes in the tree be squashed (or split). While I agree with @jbapple 's analysis that amortized that's still `O(log N)` work that needs to be done, that's only if you can identify all of the overlapping nodes without having to walk the entire tree every time. And that's where I got stuck. I don't want addRange to take `O(N)` every time.

Comment: @Moodragonx I don't understand - if I have a tree like in this image (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree#/media/File%3AUnbalanced_binary_tree.svg ) and I'm adding the interval [9,54], why would I need to visit the right child of 17? We know anything there is greater than 17 but less than 50 (50 is the root node of the tree in the image). That's O(log n) nodes visited, meaning a maximum of down the length of the left side plus down the length of the right, no?

Comment: @גלעדברקן
What I mean is, I don't know of a scheme for finding and collapsing all the nodes in the tree that need to be merged or removed during insertion or deletion, without just walking the tree. Clearly, like you noted, you could logically exclude certain paths down the tree, but I'm worried I don't know how to do that in general?
If you could describe an algorithm to do so/demonstrate it's less than `O(N)`, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Moodragonx Google something like "split binary tree at value." To insert your large, engulfing interval, first split at `low`, then split the right part of that at `high` and discard the left part of the latter - so you end up with everything lower than low and greater than high. Now merge. Does that make sense?

Comment: @גלעדברקן: I see now that visiting just O(log n) (instead of all 500000) existing nodes would suffice, and I think jbapple's amortised analysis shows why the necessary cleanup (what you're postponing to GC, and what s/he instead "front-loads") can be done in O(log n) *amortised* time.  But it seems to me that the operation you propose could lead to a very unbalanced tree...  Is it possible to restore (enough) balance in O(log n) time?  I think the answer is probably "Yes", but I'd like to see it in detail.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative might be a rope data structure ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure) ), which seems to support the operations you are asking for, implemented in `O(log n)` time. As opposed to the example in Wikipedia, yours would store `[start,end]` rather than string subsequences.

What's interesting about the rope is its efficient lookup of index-within-interval. It accomplishes this by ordering all value positions from left to right - a lower to higher positioning (of which your intervals would be a straightforward representation) can be either upwards or downwards as long as the movement is to the right - as well as relying on storing subtree size, which orients current position based on the weight on the left. Engulfing partial intervals by larger encompassing intervals could be accomplished in `O(log n)` time by updating and unlinking relevant tree segments.

Comment: Does this ignore the cost of de-allocating the deleted nodes?

Comment: @jbapple once the relevant nodes are unlinked, they are no longer part of the tree. In adding the engulfing range, the tree would be available to answer queries in `O(log n)` time, and the `k` unlinked nodes taken care of by garbage collection.

Comment: Interesting. I've never heard of the Rope data structure before and am still trying to understand how it would be used to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this allow you to identify all the nodes that would be affected by an insertion/deletion of a large interval in less than `O(N)`, with N being the number of nodes? I'm not talking about worst case, it's fine if the operation takes time linear in the number of impacted nodes, even if you try to cheat it with garbage collection it'll still (potentially) need to go through all of them. And that's okay. But using a normal BST, I can't seem to find a scheme of identifying the afflicted nodes without having to walk the whole tree.

Comment: @Moodragonx thank you for commenting. If you read about the rope in Wikipedia, you'll see it's commonly used to enable O(log n) operations related to string edits, like cut, paste, and undo. Cut & paste is similar to finding and extracting an interval - in the case of adding a larger, encompassing interval, you'd just be cutting, essentially. On the last question I asked on SO, there's a good explanation for how one C++ implementation works. That one assigns equal weight to each node - converting that kind of implementation might not be so simple, but it does show the interval extraction.

Comment: @Moodragonx - there may be a smarter way, but to adapt a classic string-type rope to store intervals, you may need to store the gaps between the intervals as flagged nodes as well (so O(2n) = O(n), just add the gap, if there is one, whenever a new interval is added) - that way there's continuity in the indexing, which is needed for queries; and probably an offset to be able to calculate the weight/size, so a record of the lowest (that's easy).

Comment: @Moodragonx In case you're still having trouble understanding - imagine that instead of the string subsequences in the Wikipedia explanation, the nodes just stored the indexes of those subsequences - that's exactly what you are asking for. Please let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: I went back and carefully considered this data structure and I'm convinced it would work with sufficient augmentations, but I think just relying on a basic binary search tree as a backing for the data structure I'd like is simpler.
Thanks for taking the time to submit an answer and discuss the intricacies of implementation with me.

Comment: @Moodragonx I think I would agree.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with storing each interval as a (start,end) couple is that if you add a new range that encompasses N previously stored intervals, you have to destroy each of these intervals, which takes N steps, whether the intervals are stored in a tree, a rope or a linked list.

*(You could leave them for automatic garbage collection, but that will take time too, and only works in some languages.)*

A possible solution for this could be to store the values (not the start and end point of intervals) in an [N-ary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ary_tree), where each node represents a range, and stores two N-bit maps, representing N sub-ranges and whether the values in those sub-ranges are all present, all absent, or mixed. In the case of mixed, there would be a pointer to a child node which represents this rub-range.

Example: (using a tree with [branching factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_factor) 8 and height 2)

```
full range: 0-511 ; store interval 100-300

0-511:
  0- 63   64-127  128-191  192-255  256-319  320-383  384-447  448-511
   0      mixed      1        1      mixed      0        0        0

64-127:
 64- 71   72- 79   80- 87   88- 95   96-103  104-111  112-119  120-127
   0        0        0        0      mixed      1        1        1

96-103:
 96   97   98   99  100  101  102  103
  0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1

256-319:
256-263  264-271  272-279  280-287  288-295  296-303  304-311  312-319
   1        1        1        1        1      mixed      0        0

296-303:
296  297  298  299  300  301  302  303
  1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0
```

So the tree would contain these five nodes:

```
- values: 00110000, mixed: 01001000, 2 pointers to sub-nodes  
  - values: 00000111, mixed: 00001000, 1 pointer to sub-node
    - values: 00001111, mixed: 00000000
  - values: 11111000, mixed: 00000100, 1 pointer to sub-node
    - values: 11111000, mixed: 00000000
```

The point of storing the interval this way is that you can discard an interval without having to actually delete it. Let's say you add a new range 200-400; in that case, you'd change the range 256-319 in the root node from "mixed" to "1", without deleting or updating the 256-319 and 296-303 nodes themselves; these nodes can be kept for later re-use (or disconnected and put in a queue of re-usable sub-trees, or deleted in a programmed garbage-collection when the programme is idling or running low on memory).

When looking up an interval, you only have to go as deep down the tree as necessary; when looking up e.g. 225-275, you'd find that 192-255 is all-present, 256-319 is mixed, 256-263 and 264-271 and 272-279 are all-present, and you'd know the answer is true. Since these values would be stored as bitmaps (one for present/absent, one for mixed/solid), all the values in a node could be checked with only a few bitwise comparisons.

Re-using nodes:

If a node has a child node, and the corresponding value is later set from mixed to all-absent or all-present, the child node no longer holds relevant values (but it is being ignored). When the value is changed back to mixed, the child node can be updated by setting all its values to its value in the parent node (before it was changed to mixed) and then making the necessary changes.

In the example above, if we add the range 0-200, this will change the tree to:

```
- values: 11110000, mixed: 00001000, 2 pointers to sub-nodes  
  - (values: 00000111, mixed: 00001000, 1 pointer to sub-node)
    - (values: 00001111, mixed: 00000000)
  - values: 11111000, mixed: 00000100, 1 pointer to sub-node
    - values: 11111000, mixed: 00000000
```

The second and third node now contain outdated values, and are being ignored. If we then delete the range 80-95, the value for range 64-127 in the root node is changed to mixed again, and the node for range 64-127 is re-used. First we set all values in it to all-present (because that was the previous value of the parent node), and then we set the values for 80-87 and 88-95 to all-absent. The third node, for range 96-103 remains out-of-use.

```
- values: 00110000, mixed: 01001000, 2 pointers to sub-nodes  
  - values: 11001111, mixed: 00000000, 1 pointer to sub-node
    - (values: 00001111, mixed: 00000000)
  - values: 11111000, mixed: 00000100, 1 pointer to sub-node
    - values: 11111000, mixed: 00000000
```

If we then added value 100, the value for range 96-103 in the second node would be changed to mixed again, and the third node would be updated to all-absent (its previous value in the second node) and then value 100 would be set to present:

```
- values: 00110000, mixed: 01001000, 2 pointers to sub-nodes  
  - values: 11000111, mixed: 00001000, 1 pointer to sub-node
    - values: 00001000, mixed: 00000000
  - values: 11111000, mixed: 00000100, 1 pointer to sub-node
    - values: 11111000, mixed: 00000000
```

---

At first it may seem that this data structure uses a lot of storage space compared to solutions which store the intervals as (start,end) pairs. However, let's look at the (theoretical) worst-case scenario, where every even number is present and every odd number is absent, across the whole 64-bit range:

```
Total range: 0 ~ 18,446,744,073,709,551,615  
Intervals:        9,223,372,036,854,775,808
```

A data structure which stores these as (start,end) pairs would use:

```
Nodes:            9,223,372,036,854,775,808  
Size of node:                            16 bytes  
TOTAL:          147,573,952,589,676,412,928 bytes
```

If the data structure uses nodes which are linked via (64-bit) pointers, that would add:

```
Data:           147,573,952,589,676,412,928 bytes
Pointers:        73,786,976,294,838,206,456 bytes
TOTAL:          221,360,928,884,514,619,384 bytes
```

An N-ary tree with branching factor 64 (and 16 for the last level, to get a total range of 10×6 + 1×4 = 64 bits) would use:

```
Nodes (branch):         285,942,833,483,841  
Size of branch:                         528 bytes  
Nodes (leaf):        18,014,398,509,481,984  
Size of leaf:                           144 bytes  
TOTAL:            2,745,051,201,444,873,744 bytes
```

which is 53.76 times less than (start,end) pair structures (or 80.64 times less including pointers).

The calculation was done with the following N-ary tree:

```
Branch (9 levels):
value: 64-bit map
mixed: 64-bit map
sub-nodes: 64 pointers
TOTAL: 528 bytes
```

```
Leaf:
value: 64-bit map
mixed: 64-bit map
sub-nodes: 64 16-bit maps (more efficient than pointing to sub-node)
TOTAL: 144 bytes
```

This is of course a worst-case comparison; the average case would depend very much on the specific input.

---

Here's a first code example I wrote to test the idea. The nodes have branching factor 16, so that every level stores 4 bits of the integers, and common bit depths can be obtained without different leaves and branches. As an example, a tree of depth 3 is created, representing a range of 4×4 = 16 bits.

```js
function setBits(pattern, value, mask) {                 // helper function (make inline)
    return (pattern & ~mask) | (value ? mask : 0);
}

function Node(value) { // CONSTRUCTOR
    this.value = value ? 65535 : 0;                      // set all values to 1 or 0
    this.mixed = 0;                                      // set all to non-mixed
    this.sub = null;                                     // no pointer array yet
}

Node.prototype.prepareSub = function(pos, mask, value) {
    if ((this.mixed & mask) == 0) {                      // not mixed, child possibly outdated
        var prev = (this.value & mask) >> pos;
        if (value == prev) return false;                 // child doesn't require setting
        if (!this.sub) this.sub = [];                    // create array of pointers
        if (this.sub[pos]) {
            this.sub[pos].value = prev ? 65535 : 0;      // update child node values
            this.sub[pos].mixed = 0;
        }
        else this.sub[pos] = new Node(prev);             // create new child node
    }
    return true;                                         // child requires setting
}

Node.prototype.set = function(value, a, b, step) {
    var posA = Math.floor(a / step), posB = Math.floor(b / step);
    var maskA = 1 << posA, maskB = 1 << posB;
    a %= step; b %= step;

    if (step == 1) {                                     // node is leaf
        var vMask = (maskB | (maskB - 1)) ^ (maskA - 1); // bits posA to posB inclusive
        this.value = setBits(this.value, value, vMask);
    }
    else if (posA == posB) {                             // only 1 sub-range to be set
        if (a == 0 && b == step - 1)                     // a-b is full sub-range
        {
            this.value = setBits(this.value, value, maskA);
            this.mixed = setBits(this.mixed, 0, maskA);
        }
        else if (this.prepareSub(posA, maskA, value)) {  // child node requires setting
            var solid = this.sub[posA].set(value, a, b, step >> 4);     // recurse
            this.value = setBits(this.value, solid ? value : 0, maskA); // set value
            this.mixed = setBits(this.mixed, solid ? 0 : 1, maskA);     // set mixed
        }
    }
    else {                                               // multiple sub-ranges to set
        var vMask = (maskB - 1) ^ (maskA | (maskA - 1)); // bits between posA and posB
        this.value = setBits(this.value, value, vMask);  // set inbetween values
        this.mixed &= ~vMask;                            // set inbetween to solid
        var solidA = true, solidB = true;
        if (a != 0 && this.prepareSub(posA, maskA, value)) {          // child needs setting
            solidA = this.sub[posA].set(value, a, step - 1, step >> 4);
        }
        if (b != step - 1 && this.prepareSub(posB, maskB, value)) {   // child needs setting
            solidB = this.sub[posB].set(value, 0, b, step >> 4);
        }
        this.value = setBits(this.value, solidA ? value : 0, maskA);  // set value
        this.value = setBits(this.value, solidB ? value : 0, maskB);
        if (solidA) this.mixed &= ~maskA; else this.mixed |= maskA;   // set mixed
        if (solidB) this.mixed &= ~maskB; else this.mixed |= maskB;
    }
    return this.mixed == 0 && this.value == 0 || this.value == 65535; // solid or mixed
}

Node.prototype.check = function(a, b, step) {
    var posA = Math.floor(a / step), posB = Math.floor(b / step);
    var maskA = 1 << posA, maskB = 1 << posB;
    a %= step; b %= step;
    var vMask = (maskB - 1) ^ (maskA | (maskA - 1));     // bits between posA and posB

    if (step == 1) {
        vMask = posA == posB ? maskA : vMask | maskA | maskB;
        return (this.value & vMask) == vMask;
    }
    if (posA == posB) {
        var present = (this.mixed & maskA) ? this.sub[posA].check(a, b, step >> 4) : this.value & maskA;
        return !!present;
    }
    var present = (this.mixed & maskA) ? this.sub[posA].check(a, step - 1, step >> 4) : this.value & maskA;
    if (!present) return false;
    present = (this.mixed & maskB) ? this.sub[posB].check(0, b, step >> 4) : this.value & maskB;
    if (!present) return false;
    return (this.value & vMask) == vMask;
}

function NaryTree(factor, depth) { // CONSTRUCTOR
    this.root = new Node();
    this.step = Math.pow(factor, depth);
}

NaryTree.prototype.addRange = function(a, b) {
    this.root.set(1, a, b, this.step);
}

NaryTree.prototype.delRange = function(a, b) {
    this.root.set(0, a, b, this.step);
}

NaryTree.prototype.hasRange = function(a, b) {
    return this.root.check(a, b, this.step);
}

var intervals = new NaryTree(16, 3);                  // create tree for 16-bit range

// CREATE RANDOM DATA AND RUN TEST
document.write("Created N-ary tree for 16-bit range.<br>Randomly adding/deleting 100000 intervals...");
for (var test = 0; test < 100000; test++) {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 61440);
    var b = a + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4096);
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) intervals.addRange(a,b);
    else intervals.delRange(a,b);
}
document.write("<br>Checking a few random intervals:<br>");
for (var test = 0; test < 8; test++) {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 65280);
    var b = a + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    document.write("Tree has interval " + a + "-" + b + " ? " + intervals.hasRange(a,b),".<br>");
}
```

---

I ran a test to check how many nodes are being created, and how many of these are active or dormant. I used a total range of 24-bit (so that I could test the worst-case without running out of memory), divided into 6 levels of 4 bits (so each node has 16 sub-ranges); the number of nodes that need to be checked or updated when adding, deleting or checking an interval is 11 or less. The maximum number of nodes in this scheme is 1,118,481.

The graph below shows the number of active nodes when you keep adding/deleting random intervals with range 1 (single integers), 1~16, 1~256 ... 1~16M (the full range).

[image: active nodes]

Adding and deleting single integers (dark green line) creates active nodes up to close to the maximum 1,118,481 nodes, with almost no nodes being made dormant. The maximum is reached after adding and deleting around 16M integers (= the number of integers in the range).

If you add and delete random intervals in a larger range, the number of nodes that are created is roughly the same, but more of them are being made dormant. If you add random intervals in the full 1~16M range (bright yellow line), less than 64 nodes are active at any time, no matter how many intervals you keep adding or deleting.

This already gives an idea of where this data structure could be useful as opposed to others: the more nodes are being made dormant, the more intervals/nodes would need to be deleted in other schemes.

On the other hand, it shows how this data structure may be too space-inefficient for certain ranges, and types and amounts of input. You could introduce a dormant node recycling system, but that takes away the advantage of the dormant nodes being immediately reusable.

---

A lot of space in the N-ary tree is taken up by pointers to child nodes. If the complete range is small enough, you could store the tree in an array. For a 32-bit range that would take 580 MB (546 MB for the "value" bitmaps and 34 MB for the "mixed" bitmaps). This is more space-efficient because you only store the bitmaps, and you don't need pointers to child nodes, because everything has a fixed place in the array. You'd have the advantage of a tree with depth 7, so any operation could be done by checking 15 "nodes" or fewer, and no nodes need to be created or deleted during add/delete/check operations.

Here's a code example I used to try out the N-ary-tree-in-an-array idea; it uses 580MB to store a N-ary tree with branching factor 16 and depth 7, for a 32-bit range (unfortunately, a range above 40 bits or so is probably beyond the memory capabilities of any normal computer). In addition to the requested functions, it can also check whether an interval is completely absent, using notValue() and notRange().

```cpp
#include <iostream>

inline uint16_t setBits(uint16_t pattern, uint16_t mask, uint16_t value) {
    return (pattern & ~mask) | (value & mask);
}

class NaryTree32 {
    uint16_t value[0x11111111], mixed[0x01111111];

    bool set(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint16_t value = 0xFFFF, uint8_t bits = 28, uint32_t offset = 0) {
        uint8_t posA = a >> bits, posB = b >> bits;
        uint16_t maskA = 1 << posA, maskB = 1 << posB;
        uint16_t mask = maskB ^ (maskA - 1) ^ (maskB - 1);

        // IF NODE IS LEAF: SET VALUE BITS AND RETURN WHETHER VALUES ARE MIXED
        if (bits == 0) {
            this->value[offset] = setBits(this->value[offset], mask, value);
            return this->value[offset] != 0 && this->value[offset] != 0xFFFF;
        }

        uint32_t offsetA = offset * 16 + posA + 1, offsetB = offset * 16 + posB + 1;
        uint32_t subMask = ~(0xFFFFFFFF << bits);
        a &= subMask; b &= subMask;

        // IF SUB-RANGE A IS MIXED OR HAS WRONG VALUE
        if (((this->mixed[offset] & maskA) != 0 || (this->value[offset] & maskA) != (value & maskA))
        && (a != 0 || posA == posB && b != subMask)) {

            // IF SUB-RANGE WAS PREVIOUSLY SOLID: UPDATE TO PREVIOUS VALUE
            if ((this->mixed[offset] & maskA) == 0) {
                this->value[offsetA] = (this->value[offset] & maskA) ? 0xFFFF : 0x0000;
                if (bits != 4) this->mixed[offsetA] = 0x0000;
            }
            // RECURSE AND IF SUB-NODE IS MIXED: SET MIXED BIT AND REMOVE A FROM MASK
            if (this->set(a, posA == posB ? b : subMask, value, bits - 4, offsetA)) {
                this->mixed[offset] |= maskA;
                mask ^= maskA;
            }
        }
        // IF SUB-RANGE B IS MIXED OR HAS WRONG VALUE
        if (((this->mixed[offset] & maskB) != 0 || (this->value[offset] & maskB) != (value & maskB))
        && b != subMask && posA != posB) {

            // IF SUB-RANGE WAS PREVIOUSLY SOLID: UPDATE SUB-NODE TO PREVIOUS VALUE
            if ((this->mixed[offset] & maskB) == 0) {
                this->value[offsetB] = (this->value[offset] & maskB) ? 0xFFFF : 0x0000;
                if (bits > 4) this->mixed[offsetB] = 0x0000;
            }
            // RECURSE AND IF SUB-NODE IS MIXED: SET MIXED BIT AND REMOVE A FROM MASK
            if (this->set(0, b, value, bits - 4, offsetB)) {
                this->mixed[offset] |= maskB;
                mask ^= maskB;
            }
        }
        // SET VALUE AND MIXED BITS THAT HAVEN'T BEEN SET YET AND RETURN WHETHER NODE IS MIXED
        if (mask) {
            this->value[offset] = setBits(this->value[offset], mask, value);
            this->mixed[offset] &= ~mask;
        }
        return this->mixed[offset] != 0 || this->value[offset] != 0 && this->value[offset] != 0xFFFF;
    }

    bool check(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint16_t value = 0xFFFF, uint8_t bits = 28, uint32_t offset = 0) {
        uint8_t posA = a >> bits, posB = b >> bits;
        uint16_t maskA = 1 << posA, maskB = 1 << posB;
        uint16_t mask = maskB ^ (maskA - 1) ^ (maskB - 1);

        // IF NODE IS LEAF: CHECK BITS A TO B INCLUSIVE AND RETURN
        if (bits == 0) {
            return (this->value[offset] & mask) == (value & mask);
        }

        uint32_t subMask = ~(0xFFFFFFFF << bits);
        a &= subMask; b &= subMask;

        // IF SUB-RANGE A IS MIXED AND PART OF IT NEEDS CHECKING: RECURSE AND RETURN IF FALSE
        if ((this->mixed[offset] & maskA) && (a != 0 || posA == posB && b != subMask)) {
            if (this->check(a, posA == posB ? b : subMask, value, bits - 4, offset * 16 + posA + 1)) {
                mask ^= maskA;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        // IF SUB-RANGE B IS MIXED AND PART OF IT NEEDS CHECKING: RECURSE AND RETURN IF FALSE
        if (posA != posB && (this->mixed[offset] & maskB) && b != subMask) {
            if (this->check(0, b, value, bits - 4, offset * 16 + posB + 1)) {
                mask ^= maskB;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        // CHECK INBETWEEN BITS (AND A AND/OR B IF NOT YET CHECKED) WHETHER SOLID AND CORRECT
        return (this->mixed[offset] & mask) == 0 && (this->value[offset] & mask) == (value & mask);
    }

    public:

    NaryTree32() { // CONSTRUCTOR: INITIALISES ROOT NODE
        this->value[0] = 0x0000;
        this->mixed[0] = 0x0000;
    }

    void addValue(uint32_t a)             {this->set(a, a);}
    void addRange(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {this->set(a, b);}
    void delValue(uint32_t a)             {this->set(a, a, 0);}
    void delRange(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {this->set(a, b, 0);}
    bool hasValue(uint32_t a)             {return this->check(a, a);}
    bool hasRange(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {return this->check(a, b);}
    bool notValue(uint32_t a)             {return this->check(a, a, 0);}
    bool notRange(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {return this->check(a, b, 0);}
};

int main() {
    NaryTree32 *tree = new NaryTree32();

    tree->addRange(4294967280, 4294967295);
    std::cout << tree->hasRange(4294967280, 4294967295) << "\n";
    tree->delValue(4294967290);
    std::cout << tree->hasRange(4294967280, 4294967295) << "\n";
    tree->addRange(1000000000, 4294967295);
    std::cout << tree->hasRange(4294967280, 4294967295) << "\n";
    tree->delRange(2000000000, 4294967280);
    std::cout << tree->hasRange(4294967280, 4294967295) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a really interesting alternative scheme for doing this. I haven't fully wrapped my head around this but by this point I have a working implementation backed by a self-balancing bst storing (start,end) pairs and this seems a bit more involved to implement correctly.
One point on comparing them, however, is the N previously stored intervals that get need to be destroyed are free operations amortized over the inserts.
Asymptotically this seems to have similar runtime and space costs but I'd be interested to see how they compare in practice.

Comment: @Moodragonx I added a C++ code example for the tree-in-an-array idea. If you don't need the full 64-bit range, you could use this to compare speeds and memory requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Interval trees seem to be geared toward storing overlapping intervals, while in your case that doesn't make sense. An interval tree could hold millions of small overlapping intervals, which together form only a handful of longer non-overlapping intervals.

If you want to store only non-overlapping intervals, then adding or deleting an interval may involve deleting a number of consecutive intervals that fall within the new interval. So quickly finding consecutive intervals, and efficient deletion of a potentially large number of intervals are important.

That sounds like a job for the humble linked list. When inserting a new interval, you'd:

- Search the position of the new interval's starting point.
- If it is inside an existing interval, go on to find the position of the end point, while extending the existing interval and deleting all intervals you pass on the way.
- If it is inbetween existing intervals, check if the end point comes before the next existing interval. If it does, create a new interval. If the end point comes after the start of the next existing interval, change the starting point of the next interval, and then go on to find the end point as explained in the previous paragraph.

Deleting an interval would be largely the same: you truncate the intervals that the starting point and end point are inside of, and delete all the intervals inbetween.

The average and worst-case complexity of this are N/2 and N, where N is the number of intervals in the linked list. You could improve this by adding a method to avoid having to iterate over the whole list to find the starting point; if you know the range and distribution of the values, this could be something like a hash table; e.g. if the values are from 1 to X and the distribution is uniform, you'd store a table of length Y, where each item points to the interval that starts before the value X/Y. When adding an interval (A,B), you'd look up table[A/Y] and start iterating over the linked list from there. The choice of value for Y would be determined by how much space you want to use, versus how close you want to get to the actual position of the starting point. The complexities would then drop by a factor Y.

(If you work in a language where you can short-circuit a linked list, and just leave the chain of objects you cut loose to be garbage-collected, you could find the location of the starting point and end point independently, connect them, and skip the deletion of all the intervals inbetween. I don't know whether this would actually increase speed in practice.)

---

Here's a start of a code example, with the three range functions, but without further optimisation:

```js
function Interval(a, b, n) {
    this.start = a;
    this.end = b;
    this.next = n;
}

function IntervalList() {
    this.first = null;
}

IntervalList.prototype.addRange = function(a, b) {
    if (!this.first || b < this.first.start - 1) {
        this.first = new Interval(a, b, this.first); // insert as first element
        return;
    }
    var i = this.first;
    while (a > i.end + 1 && i.next && b >= i.next.start - 1) {
        i = i.next;                                  // locate starting point
    }
    if (a > i.end + 1) {                             // insert as new element
        i.next = new Interval(a, b, i.next);
        return;
    }
    var j = i.next;
    while (j && b >= j.start - 1) {                  // locate end point
        i.end = j.end;
        i.next = j = j.next;                         // discard overlapping interval
    }
    if (a < i.start) i.start = a;                    // update interval start
    if (b > i.end) i.end = b;                        // update interval end
}

IntervalList.prototype.delRange = function(a, b) {
    if (!this.first || b < this.first.start) return; // range before first interval
    var i = this.first;
    while (i.next && a > i.next.start) i = i.next;   // a in or after interval i
    if (a > i.start) {                               // a in interval
        if (b < i.end) {                             // range in interval -> split
            i.next = new Interval(b + 1, i.end, i.next);
            i.end = a - 1;
            return;
        }
        if (a <= i.end) i.end = a - 1;               // truncate interval
    }
    var j = a > i.start ? i.next : i;
    while (j && b >= j.end) j = j.next;              // b before or in interval j
    if (a <= this.first.start) this.first = j;       // short-circuit list
    else i.next = j;
    if (j && b >= j.start) j.start = b + 1;          // truncate interval
}

IntervalList.prototype.hasRange = function(a, b) {
    if (!this.first) return false;                   // empty list
    var i = this.first;
    while (i.next && a > i.end) i = i.next;          // a before or in interval i
    return a >= i.start && b <= i.end;               // range in interval ?
}

IntervalList.prototype.addValue = function(a) {
    this.addRange(a, a);                             // could be optimised
}

IntervalList.prototype.delValue = function(a) {
    this.delRange(a, a);                             // could be optimised
}

IntervalList.prototype.hasValue = function(a) {
    return this.hasRange(a, a);                      // could be optimised
}

IntervalList.prototype.print = function() {
    var i = this.first;
    if (i) do document.write("(" + i.start + "-" + i.end + ") "); while (i = i.next);
    document.write("<br>");
}

var intervals = new IntervalList();
intervals.addRange(100,199);
document.write("+ (100-199) &rarr; "); intervals.print();
intervals.addRange(300,399);
document.write("+ (300-399) &rarr; "); intervals.print();
intervals.addRange(200,299);
document.write("+ (200-299) &rarr; "); intervals.print();
intervals.delRange(225,275);
document.write("− (225-275) &rarr; "); intervals.print();
document.write("(150-200) ? " + intervals.hasRange(150,200) + "<br>");
document.write("(200-300) ? " + intervals.hasRange(200,300) + "<br>");
```

Comment: Pretty cool. Don't see linked lists in algorithmic design very often.
I'm actually hoping to use this in a pretty performance-sensitive system that will be seeing large volumes of data so I'm a bit wary of linear-time operations. Though, the tree-based solution may also need to have linear time range-based operations so I'll give this more thought.
Thanks for the illustrative code snippet :).

Comment: @Moodragonx I saw a question a couple of months ago about an optimisation that could work for this, but unfortunately I can't seem to find it now, so I'll have to work from memory. Do you know anything about the distribution of the values?

Comment: Hmm in practice I'll be using the range-based operations a lot more, and they'll be in large blocks of many thousands or hundreds of thousands. The ranges may or may not be disjoint but usually mostly time localized: intervals near each other will likely be inserted closely near each other in time.

However I do think it'll be too slow to use a linked list for contains queries.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has suggested [segment trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) over the integer domain of stored values. (When used in geometric applications like graphics in 2d and 3d, they're called quadtrees and octrees resp.) Insert, delete, and lookup will have time and space complexity proportional to the number of bits in (maxval - minval), that is log_2 (maxval - minval), the max and min values of the integer data domain.

In a nutshell, we are encoding a set of integers in [minval, maxval]. A node at topmost level 0 represents that entire range.  Each successive level's nodes represent sub-ranges of approximate size (maxval - minval) / 2^k.  When a node is included, some subset of it's corresponding values are part of the represented set.  When it's a leaf, *all* of its values are in the set. When it's absent, none are.

E.g. if minval=0 and maxval=7, then the k=1 children of the k=0 node represent [0..3] and [4..7]. Their children at level k=2 are [0..1][2..3][4..5], and [6..7], and the k=3 nodes represent individual elements. The set {[1..3], [6..7]} would be the tree (levels left to right):

```
[0..7] -- [0..3] -- [0..1]
       |         |        `-[1] 
       |         `- [2..3]
        ` [4..7]
                 `- [6..7]
```

It's not hard to see that space for the tree will be O(m log (maxval - minval)) where m is the number of intervals stored in the tree.

It's not common to use segment trees with dynamic insert and delete, but the algorithms turn out to be fairly simple. It takes some care to ensure the number of nodes is minimized.

Here is some very lightly tested java code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class SegmentTree {
  // Shouldn't differ by more than Long.MAX_VALUE to prevent overflow.
  static final long MIN_VAL = 0;
  static final long MAX_VAL = Long.MAX_VALUE;
  Node root;

  static class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node(Node left, Node right) {
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
    }
  }

  private static boolean isLeaf(Node node) {
    return node != null && node.left == null && node.right == null;
  }

  private static Node reset(Node node, Node left, Node right) {
    if (node == null) {
      return new Node(left, right);
    }
    node.left = left;
    node.right = right;
    return node;
  }

  /**
   * Accept an arbitrary subtree rooted at a node representing a subset S of the range [lo,hi] and
   * transform it into a subtree representing S + [a,b]. It's assumed a >= lo and b <= hi.
   */
  private static Node add(Node node, long lo, long hi, long a, long b) {
    // If the range is empty, the interval tree is always null.
    if (lo > hi) return null;
    // If this is a leaf or insertion is outside the range, there's no change.
    if (isLeaf(node) || a > b || b < lo || a > hi) return node;
    // If insertion fills the range, return a leaf.
    if (a == lo && b == hi) return reset(node, null, null);
    // Insertion doesn't cover the range. Get the children, if any.
    Node left = null, right = null;
    if (node != null) {
      left = node.left;
      right = node.right;
    }
    // Split the range and recur to insert in halves.
    long mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    left = add(left, lo, mid, a, Math.min(b, mid));
    right = add(right, mid + 1, hi, Math.max(a, mid + 1), b);
    // Build a new node, coallescing to leaf if both children are leaves.
    return isLeaf(left) && isLeaf(right) ? reset(node, null, null) : reset(node, left, right);
  }

  /**
   * Accept an arbitrary subtree rooted at a node representing a subset S of the range [lo,hi] and
   * transform it into a subtree representing range(s) S - [a,b].  It's assumed a >= lo and b <= hi.
   */
  private static Node del(Node node, long lo, long hi, long a, long b) {
    // If the tree is null, we can't remove anything, so it's still null
    // or if the range is empty, the tree is null.
    if (node == null || lo > hi) return null;
    // If the deletion is outside the range, there's no change.
    if (a > b || b < lo || a > hi) return node; 
    // If deletion fills the range, return an empty tree.
    if (a == lo && b == hi) return null;
    // Deletion doesn't fill the range. 
    // Replace a leaf with a tree that has the deleted portion removed. 
    if (isLeaf(node)) {
      return add(add(null, lo, hi, b + 1, hi), lo, hi, lo, a - 1);
    }
    // Not a leaf. Get children, if any.
    Node left = node.left, right = node.right;
    long mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    // Recur to delete in child ranges.
    left = del(left, lo, mid, a, Math.min(b, mid));
    right = del(right, mid + 1, hi, Math.max(a, mid + 1), b);
    // Build a new node, coallescing to empty tree if both children are empty.
    return left == null && right == null ? null : reset(node, left, right);
  }

  private static class NotContainedException extends Exception {};

  private static void verifyContains(Node node, long lo, long hi, long a, long b)
      throws NotContainedException {
    // If this is a leaf or query is empty, it's always contained.
    if (isLeaf(node) || a > b) return;
    // If tree or search range is empty, the query is never contained.
    if (node == null || lo > hi) throw new NotContainedException();
    long mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    verifyContains(node.left, lo, mid, a, Math.min(b, mid));
    verifyContains(node.right, mid + 1, hi, Math.max(a, mid + 1), b);
  }

  SegmentTree addRange(long a, long b) {
    root = add(root, MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL, Math.max(a, MIN_VAL), Math.min(b, MAX_VAL));
    return this;
  }

  SegmentTree addVal(long a) {
    return addRange(a, a);
  }

  SegmentTree delRange(long a, long b) {
    root = del(root, MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL, Math.max(a, MIN_VAL), Math.min(b, MAX_VAL));
    return this;
  }

  SegmentTree delVal(long a) {
    return delRange(a, a);
  }

  boolean containsVal(long a) {
    return containsRange(a, a);
  }

  boolean containsRange(long a, long b) {
    try {
      verifyContains(root, MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL, Math.max(a, MIN_VAL), Math.min(b, MAX_VAL));
      return true;
    } catch (NotContainedException expected) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private static final boolean PRINT_SEGS_COALESCED = true;

  /** Gather a list of possibly coalesced segments for printing. */
  private static void gatherSegs(List<Long> segs, Node node, long lo, long hi) {
    if (node == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
      if (PRINT_SEGS_COALESCED && !segs.isEmpty() && segs.get(segs.size() - 1) == lo - 1) {
        segs.remove(segs.size() - 1);
      } else {
        segs.add(lo);
      }
      segs.add(hi);
    } else {
      long mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
      gatherSegs(segs, node.left, lo, mid);
      gatherSegs(segs, node.right, mid + 1, hi);
    }
  }

  SegmentTree print() {
    List<Long> segs = new ArrayList<>();
    gatherSegs(segs, root, MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL);
    Iterator<Long> it = segs.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      long a = it.next();
      long b = it.next();
      System.out.print("[" + a + "," + b + "]");
    }
    System.out.println();
    return this;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    SegmentTree tree = new SegmentTree()
        .addRange(0, 4).print()
        .addRange(6, 7).print()
        .delVal(2).print()
        .addVal(5).print()
        .addRange(0,1000).print()
        .addVal(5).print()
        .delRange(22, 777).print();
    System.out.println(tree.containsRange(3, 20));
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this perform when to deleting nodes, i.e. when you add or delete a large range that encompasses a large number of previously added smaller intervals? I guess it's similar to an interval tree in this respect?

Comment: @m69 No matter what the size of the range, it's represented by O(log(maxval - minval)) nodes. Inserting or deleting a node is constant time. So O(log(maxval - minval)) is also the time bound for insert and delete. Operationally, insert and delete prune the descendants of the large inserted or deleted range without ever examining them. (This assumes that you don't do something dumb like traverse the pruned trees to free memory. A copying garbage collection strategy is necessary.)

Comment: I guess my second answer is a variation of a segment tree, but instead of a binary tree the nodes have 64 (or 16 in the code example) sub-nodes, and the presence of these sub-ranges is stored in a bitmap so that the sub-trees can simply be ignored if their range is deleted, and re-used if (part of) their range is added again later.