# What abstract data type is this?

Tags: algorithm, collections, abstraction, abstract-data-type

Is the following a common data type (i.e. does it have a name)?

Its unique characteristic is, unlike a regular `Set`, that it contains the "universe" on initialisation with `O(C)` memory overhead, and a max memory overhead of `O(N/2)` (which only occurs when you remove every-other element):

```
> s = new Structure(701)
s = Structure(0-700)

> s.remove(100)
s = Structure(0-99, 101-700)

> s.add(100)
s = Structure(0-700)

> s.remove(200)
s = Structure(0-199, 201-700)

> s.remove(202)
s = Structure(0-199, 201, 203-700)

> s.removeAll()
s = Structure()
```

Does something like this have a standard name?

Comment: [Range tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree)? A remove operation here would be equivalent to a node split + resize operation in the range tree.

Comment: What makes you think something so specific would have a name? This kind of sounds like a disguised no-research request for an implementation which can achieve this.

Comment: No name, but a couple of ideas about how to implement this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522165/efficient-data-structure-for-storing-a-long-sequence-of-mostly-consecutive-int/

Comment: @Dukeling already implemented this in Scala (I know there's nothing in the standard collection libs like this). Just wanted to pick a decent name for my type (have previously been calling it a `SparseRange`).

Comment: I'd call it a run-length-encoded bit-vector because its semantics are bit-vector, and its print representation shows contiguous blocks.

Comment: A bit off-topic: when using it, just be sure that the overhead of managing the list of ranges is worth it, compared to a plain bit vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a `Compressed Bit Set` or `Compressed Bitmap`.

A `Bit Set` or `Bitmap` is a set specifically designed for storing `Integer`s. Most languages offer standard implementations of these. They typically work by assigning a `1` to the `N`th bit in an internal array of `Integers` where `N` is the number you're adding to the set. `0` indicates the value is not present. The memory usage for these types of `Bit Sets` is dictated by the largest number you store.

A `Compressed Bit Set` is one that compacts ranges of `0`s and `1`s.

In this case, the question demonstrates a type of compression called "run-length-encoding" (thank you @Ralf Kleberhoff), so it is specifically a `Run-length Encoded Bitmap`.

Common implementations of `Compressed Bitmaps` (from newest-to-oldest) are:

- [Roaring Bitmaps](https://github.com/RoaringBitmap/RoaringBitmap) (only one to provide "good random access")
- [EWAH](https://github.com/lemire/javaewah)
- [WAH](https://sdm.lbl.gov/fastbit/compression.html)
- [Oracle BBC](https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/dcc/1995/7012/00/70120476.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this many times in the past and seen it used in things like plane-sweep algorithms for polygon clipping.

Sometimes the abstract data type it represents is just a set, and the data structure is an optimization.  I use this for representing the set of matching characters given by a regex expression like [^a-zA-z0-9.-], for example, and to perform intersection, union, and other operations on those sets.

This sort of data structure is implemented on top of some other ordered set or map structure, by simply storing the keys where membership in the set changes instead of the keys in the set itself.  In all the other cases where I've seen this sort of thing done, the authors refer to that underlying structure instead of giving a name to the concept itself.

I like the idea of having a name for it, though, since as I said I've used it myself many times.  Maybe I would call it an "in & out set" in honor of the hamburger chain I liked the best back when I ate hamburgers.